# PostgreSql backup bat file not creating backup file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, database-backups

I have created a bat file to take backup of my `postgresql` database. The following is my bat file look like:

```
@echo off
   for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
   )
   set datestr=%month%_%day%_%year%
   echo datestr is %datestr%

   set BACKUP_FILE=backup_%datestr%.backup
   echo backup file name is %BACKUP_FILE%
   SET PGPASSWORD=password
   echo on
   bin\pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% DATABASESAMPLE
```

I created as `postgresqlBackup.bat` and I put it inside `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin` postgresql instalation directory.

Before setting pgjob scheduler **I tried double click on that bat file** for checking whether it is working or not. But no backup files got created inside that particular folder. Please guide me. Am I looking on different location?

Comment: Run it from the command line rather than double clicking it, then you can see the error messages (if there are any)

Comment: ok buddy I will do that!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am getting error as The system cannot find the path specified. Where should I correct it. Can You help me buddy. I am new to bat.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pROBLEM WAS IN PATH CHANGED bin\pg_dump  TO pg_dump .Working

Comment: I tried this batch file but i encountered error: 'pg_dump' is not recognized  as an internal or external command.  What till i do???